# Show and Hide Text Box With A Timer

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need some help with a VBA for a textbox. This Macro will be embedded into a button.

I have this code below and what it does is that it show/hide the textbox password whenever the button is pressed. The textbox Input Mask property is set to password by default.

I am trying to edit it such that it will show and hide with only one click of the button. I need help putting a timer to the show password for 4 seconds before automatically hiding it again.. Is this possible?

```
Sub example()

If Text1.InputMask = "Password" Then
    Text1.InputMask = ""
Else
    Text1.InputMask = "Password"
End If

End Sub
```

I'm quite the novice at VBA so any help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need a "timer" - You just need to tell VBA to do nothing for a period of time. Here I defined the time to be 1 second. Put a `DoEvents` in the loop so it doesn't appear to freeze.

```
Private Sub btnShowPassword_Click()
  Dim dtWait As Date

  If Text1.InputMask = "Password" Then
    Text1.InputMask = ""
    dtWait = DateAdd("s", 1, Now) ' 1 Second
    Do Until Now > dtWait
       DoEvents
    Loop
    Text1.InputMask = "Password"
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will give it a try and come back to you :)